# Removing "Home" from the title

Tags: theming, 8

How do I remove *Home* from the page title?

I added in page.twig.html this part of code.

```
{% if not is_front %}

      {{ page.content }}

      {% endif %}
```

The title appears as follows.

> [image: screenshot]

I just want it to be *Nekretnina.ba*, without *Home |*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override `html.twig.php` in your template, not `page.twig.html`. May I also suggest [metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) for better control over page titles?